# How to resize the box but still put text inside it at center?

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML:

```
<div class='title'><h2>Title</h2></div>
```

I want to resize the box, so wrote the following:

```
.title {
display: block;
border-radius: 12px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

However, the resultant box looks a bit big, hence I tried to resize it.

```
.title {
height: 90%;
}
```

However, even if I tried to write the above code, the resultant box isn't affected by the settings.

```
.title {
height: 100px;
}
```

This worked. However, the text inside it is no more on the center, so I tried to make it at center.

```
.title h2 {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, this doesn't work.

So how can I resize the box but still have text inside it intact?

Also, why the first height setting doesn't work but the second does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYXa5/))

```
.title h2 {
    margin:0px;
    line-height:100px; /* change to fit your needs */
}
```

`vertical-align` is not the best approach in this case..

**UPDATE:**

Use [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYXa5/1/) instead, it uses `vertical-align` as you wanted and you don't need to apply the `line-height` of `h2`.. the secret is making the parent `display:table;` and the child `display:table-cell`:

```
.title {
    display: table; /* Here's the trick */
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
}

.title h2 {
    display:table-cell; /* Here's the trick */
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got to know that this approach has to set the value of both .title's height and .title h2's line-height at same, right? Your code worked as expected, but doesn't this look devastated when it's viewed on mobile? That's why I wanted to set height by percentages, which I think should be used on responsive sites...

Comment: @user2360798 Updated. this should now work as you want. check the [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYXa5/1/)

Comment: While I still have to understand the tricks on `display` part, your updated code worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2360798 Thanks. glad to help. explanation in short: vertical-align works differently on table cells and divs. your wanted behaviour is the table cell one so by setting display:table-cell you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/9NQu2/). You can set `line-height` property to achieve this.

```
h2{line-height: 50px;}
```